# C# ExecuteNonQuery() doesn't return row count from oracle procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, plsqldeveloper, oledbcommand

As the title states, when I call the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method it returns 1 when the inserted records where 14, for example. I tried adding the `SET FEEDBACK ON` command in my package procedure, but still get the same result. Does anyone has any tips on this...

```
//C#
int rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

--ORACLE
SET FEEDBACK ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ABC IS
  PROCEDURE insert_data
  BEGIN
    ...
  END insert_data;
END ABC;

//Result of rowcount
 rowCount = 1;
```

PS: I guess I could just return the inserted values from the procedure OUT param, but I just wanted to know if I'm missing something here. Thanks!

Comment: Check for any set statements, updates etc AFTER your insert, I'd bet that's the issue, they all affect rowcount

Comment: This value is valid only for DML operations and not for PL/SQL blocks. You will always get the value as 1 for any PL/SQL block or stored procedure.

Comment: And is there another way of retrieving an insert rowcount from ExecuteNonQuery() with Oracle procedure? Thanks for your help @:user1892538